# Player not working of some videos and audios

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, exoplayer2.x

I have an old app in the playstore that I wanted to update (almost 3 years). I've fixed deprecated codes and libraries except this ExoPlayer library. I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pEkg1mQihmU&t=594s) and it worked without issue. But then when I use my actual mp3/mp4 files, I've got an error which is new for me. I've already searched over the internet about this issue but no luck.

Here is my code

```
   private lateinit var binding: PlayerActivityBinding
    private var exoPlayer: ExoPlayer? = null
    private var playbackPosition = 0L
    private var playWhenReady = true

// some override ...

  private fun preparePlayer() {
        exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build()
        exoPlayer?.playWhenReady = true
        binding.playerView.player = exoPlayer
        val defaultHttpDataSourceFactory = DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory()
        val mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(URL)
        val mediaSource =
            DashMediaSource.Factory(defaultHttpDataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(mediaItem)
        exoPlayer?.setMediaSource(mediaSource)
        exoPlayer?.seekTo(playbackPosition)
        exoPlayer?.playWhenReady = playWhenReady
        exoPlayer?.prepare()
    }

    private fun  releasePlayer(){
        exoPlayer?.let { player ->
            playbackPosition = player.currentPosition
            playWhenReady = player.playWhenReady
            player.release()
            exoPlayer = null
        }
    }

companion object{
        const val URL =
            "https://bitmovin-a.akamaihd.net/content/MI201109210084_1/mpds/f08e80da-bf1d-4e3d-8899-f0f6155f6efa.mpd"
    }
```

My actual media file
http://mgb-sda-lyrics.com/media_files/10000_reasons_blessed_the_lord.mp3

Here is the exception

```
V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 4488
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 213679361
V/FA: onActivityCreated
D/mgb.com.sdalyricsplus.newActivities.NewKaraokePage: onCreate: *******************************************
I/ExoPlayerImpl: Init d76898c [ExoPlayerLib/2.18.4] [2027, V2032, vivo, 31]
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 213679574
I/XDR::VRT: sc is not valid!
V/ImeFocusController: onWindowFocus: DecorView@95743fd[NewKaraokePage] softInputMode=STATE_UNSPECIFIED|ADJUST_PAN|IS_FORWARD_NAVIGATION
D/ImeFocusController: onViewFocusChanged, view=DecorView@95743fd[NewKaraokePage], mServedView=null
V/ImeFocusController: checkFocus: view=null next=DecorView@95743fd[NewKaraokePage] force=false package=<none>
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0xb4000078f8ab1290 (CardView) with handle 0xb4000078089fcab0
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Playback error
      com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleIoException(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:644)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:614)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:334)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
     Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.ParserException
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.dash.manifest.DashManifestParser.parse(DashManifestParser.java:112)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.dash.manifest.DashManifestParser.parse(DashManifestParser.java:66)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.ParsingLoadable.load(ParsingLoadable.java:176)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:412)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
     Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unterminated entity ref (position:TEXT @4:363 in java.io.InputStreamReader@f6ba349) 
        at com.android.org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.readEntity(KXmlParser.java:1220)
        at com.android.org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.readValue(KXmlParser.java:1402)
        at com.android.org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:393)
        at com.android.org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:313)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.dash.manifest.DashManifestParser.parse(DashManifestParser.java:104)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.dash.manifest.DashManifestParser.parse(DashManifestParser.java:66) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.ParsingLoadable.load(ParsingLoadable.java:176) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:412) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

Gradle

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.18.4'
    implementation 'androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer-ima:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-ima:2.18.4'
```

note that the old version of exoplayer is working with my actual mp3 file. But in this latest version, it won't.

Comment: According to the log it fails to parse the input, according to my VLC the file is mp2 not mp3. Not sure if playback is supported on on android via ExoPlayer

Comment: @orhtej2 the file is working without issue in my outdated app. Very weird when not working in the latest version of exoPlayer.

Comment: It is possible to install ffmpeg exension to allow playback, perhaps older version had it bundled?

Comment: The log error you have shared shows and an MPEG DASH file parsing error, not an mp3 file. Presumably this is the BitMovin test video in your code snippet but this URL plays fine in the ExoPlayer east player. I think you will have to share more detail of your code and logs to help people help you.

Comment: While I don't have the answer, you may try playing around with MimeTypes for media item. It helps tell ExoPlayer how to decode your link. use something similar to 
        MediaItem.Builder builder = new MediaItem.Builder();
        builder.setUri(Uri.parse(webMVideoUrl));
        builder.setMimeType(MimeTypes.VIDEO_WEBM);